# Why isn't my Laravel route working? mod_rewrite enabled

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-4

I have the simple code in my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});


Route::get('/mypage', function()
{
    echo 'mypage';
});
```

Visiting mysite.dev/ will return the hello view.  However, visiting mysite.dev/mypage gives me a 404.  In my phpinfo(); I'm showing mod_rewrite enabled (as seen here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u972n1rcdbsambg/Screenshot%202014-07-09%2022.27.04.png)

Any idea why this wouldn't work?  I'm running Mac OS X Mavericks with apache2 and PHP with Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed this from

`AllowOverride None`

to

`AllowOverride All`

in your `apache2.conf`?

Comment: That was it!  We're back in business!  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should try returning echo:

```
Route::get('/mypage', function()
{
    return echo 'mypage';
});
```

I hope this helped, cheers!

Comment: Could you check (assuming you are using apache) that your override settings is set to all. You can find the folder in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf`

Comment: returning `echo`? really?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could be missing the .htaccess file - it's super easy to miss this if you're copying files with finder on OS X because dotfiles are hidden by default.

Check that this file is in your /public directory - https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess